# JSDoc generic typedef for TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, jsdoc

I am using JSDoc in a JavaScript project which is checked using the TypeScript compiler.

In TypeScript, I can create a generic type like so:

```js
type Optional<TType extends string> = { type: TType; optional?: boolean; } | { type: `${TType}?` };
type OptionalThing = Optional<'thing'>;
```

The resolved and flattened value of `OptionalThing` is now this:

```js
type OptionalThing = 
  | { type: 'thing'; optional?: boolean; }
  | { type: 'thing?'; }
```

This type creates a type union where one member type has the literal and const `thing` value for the `type`  field and it has an additional `optional` boolean field and the other member type has literal and const `thing?` for the `type` field and doesn't have the `optional` field.

The `?` suffix on `type` is a short-hand syntax for marking a thing as optional in the problem I am solving so specifying `optional` in addition needs to be forbidden otherwise it would be possible to represent an invalid value: `{ type: 'thing?', optional: false }`.

In other words:

```js
/* These are allowed - they conform to the type */
const optionalThing1: OptionalThing = { type: 'thing?' };
const optionalThing2: OptionalThing = { type: 'thing', optional: true };
const optionalThing3: OptionalThing = { type: 'thing', optional: false };

// This is disallowed, `optional` cannot be specified while `type` has `?` suffix
const optionalThing4: OptionalThing = { type: 'thing?', optional: false };

// This is disallowed, `type` must be either `thing` or `thing?` const string
const optionalThing5: OptionalThing = { type: 'not literally "thing"' };
```

[Playground (configured to TypeScript)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=9&ssc=1&pln=8&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBA8mwEsD2A7AhgGwDwBUfmggA9gIUATAZykuACcEUBzAPigF4oBvKUSALih4CAbihJ4ydBgD8ggEZIkGCGhRiAvlAA+3XgUEADACRdhkDTMNQNIgFB9ocRKkw4AFoyYdYk19gByYE9mAJZ7OwBjVFpxP2kPLwBGQWcpNxDvTh5HQSDMmQCbe2iUWIkXBMyAJlT4jK8fHIMofK8AgBo4ysxBegBXaFsomOBu9IxE5gBmOp7JzKb9AVbg9q6KicEAM0xKIZLR8f8ppgAWOYnTpdzVgs7j6R29g5Gysc2TzIBWS6-G7LLCB5FBIMYYBCkOiYDAgKAAIjWzHhRWGQA)

I am having trouble translating this to JSDoc that would have the same behavior in TypeScript. I tried this:

```js
/** @typedef {{ type: T; optional?: boolean; } | { type: `${T}?`; }} Type<T> */
/** @template {string} T */

/** @typedef {Type<'thing'>} ThingType */
// Error: Type 'Type' is not generic.
```

[Playground (configured to JavaScript)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?filetype=js#code/PQKhAIAEBcE8AcCmATRAzcBvT45IFzgAqA3OAPbzQCW5AdgIYA2A-IQEbnlOIN1kBfcAB8suBIkIADACSYiAllMFCiEgDxEAfOBDAAUKAgxEAW3hMG0RFgDO0AE7U6Ac1W6DhsFDwp0WNSR1AHJoAAtnF2CtVQjXQJs9fSA)

How can I made a generic `typedef` in JSDoc such that the above TypeScript logic works the same way when TypeScript checks the JavaScript and JSDoc version?

Comment: I would define  complex types in `d.ts` files and just use them in JS

Comment: How do you do that? Can I do that using `/** @type {import('types.d.ts')} */`?

Comment: no need for the `d.ts` If you export it should work with `import('./types').Generic<{ o: string }>`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your code is almost right, you just have to place in the same JSDoc comment both the `@template` and `@typedef` tags, like this:

```
/** 
 * @typedef {{ type: T; optional?: boolean; } | { type: `${T}?`; }} Type<T>
 * @template {string} T
 */

/**
 * @typedef {Type<'thing'>} ThingType
 */
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?declaration=false&target=9&jsx=0&ts=4.8.0-beta&ssl=8&ssc=4&pln=1&pc=1&filetype=js#code/PQKhAIChwgBAXAngBwKYBNUDNwG9fhJoBc4AKgNzgD2y8AltQHYCGANgPykBG11bqFkyoBfcAB88hFKlIADACS4yIjnNFiyMgDxkAfNDjxUAW2RsWxvAGd4AJ3pMA5psPBIkUCEPgEMzDjKOgDk8AAWjk7BepoRzlpobh6eEGRhqNao4Cx2Wexs1ADuGOAAtITpiOAAxsxY1HYmhNQVWURZIO5evu3kcU4JHe61TLY0dIysbGmRAIzgALxS7aSh-RzB4CIUKUYyfZGDMMPMY7QMzOwzzgBMi8syq+GRwQA04xdTpPYArlnbux6+2uA32nUgIzOE0u036AGZ7gQVuA1i93udJuxSFh2JktjtPMADtZwPQSegyfkihh3nIMTC5DUhExqPBwNwstY0NV6Fh6CVChEBOA5O1GWEWCS5GpwNYflg+QAPQF+NAHeJgk6jNn0qYggAsiOkJBRz2cG3R0K+4BxbDxAMJxNJ5MpbAKxXQtLF4BMPzGHPAqHo4VQdhFZqcjIa4fWjMhbNsDmcKt6IKO4PjH0xsMiAFYjcjgiy2Wxg6H8lUAEQRyubbZAA)

In general, when you need to define a generic type you'll need to have alongside that `@typedef` tag also a `@template` tag in the same JSDoc comment.

You can't however place the `ThingType` `typedef` in the same JSDoc, otherwise it will become a generic type as well.