# JSDoc generic typedef for TypeScript function

Tags: typescript, jsdoc, tsd-jsdoc

I'm using JSDoc in a `mjs` to mimic a `ts` function that I have. The `mjs` is checked using the TypeScript compiler. The original function (overloaded), from `ts` file is like this:

```
export function inline<TypeS extends boolean, TypeT = unknown, TypeF = undefined>(S?: TypeS, T?: TypeT, F?: TypeF): TypeS extends true ? TypeT : TypeF {}

export function inline<TypeS extends boolean, TypeT = unknown, TypeF = undefined>(
    S?: TypeS,
    T?: TypeT,
    F?: TypeF,
): unknown {}
```

I'm trying something like:

```
/**
 * @callback Inline
 * @param {TypeS} S
 * @param {TypeT} T
 * @param {TypeF} F
 * @return {TypeS extends true ? TypeT : TypeF}
 * @type {Inline}
 */
export function inline(
    S,
    T,
    F,
) {}
```

That is almost what I expect, but, I haven't the generic types and default values of generics. Is there a way to do it properly with JSDoc?

The content that I'm using to trying to follow to solve is:

- [How to pass a generic type argument with jsdoc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65689718/how-to-pass-a-generic-type-argument-with-jsdoc)
- [JSDoc Generic Typedef for Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73237490/jsdoc-generic-typedef-for-typescript/73238823#73238823)
- [Typescript function overloads with JSDoc](https://austingil.com/typescript-function-overloads-with-jsdoc/)
- [Generic Types](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/Generic-Types)
- [JSDoc Supported Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsdoc-supported-types.html#template)

But tryng by pieces, without overload first, and then, maybe, with overload, if possible (I really don't understand well this thing, it's tricky for me)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you forgot to define the templates

```js
/**
 * @template {boolean} TypeS
 * @template [TypeT=unknown]
 * @template [TypeF=undefined]
 * @param {TypeS} [S]
 * @param {TypeT} [T]
 * @param {TypeF} [F]
 * @return {TypeS extends true ? TypeT : TypeF}
 */
export function inline(
    S,
    T,
    F,
) { }
```

Comment: Much better, but there is a subtle difference:
mjs with JSdoc:

```js
function inline<TypeS extends boolean, TypeT extends unknown, TypeF extends unknown>(S?: TypeS | undefined, T?: TypeT | undefined, F?: TypeF | undefined, ...args: any[]): TypeS extends true ? TypeT : TypeF
```

ts file:
```ts
function inline<TypeS extends boolean, TypeT = unknown, TypeF = undefined>(S?: State | undefined, T?: TypeF | undefined, F?: TypeF | undefined): TypeS extends true ? TypeT : TypeF
```

Comment: seems like JSDoc ignores the templates like:

```
 * @template {\*} TypeT = unknown
 * @template {\*} TypeF = undefined
```

and adds and ...args: any[]